# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test Statistic

Tags: scipy, statistics

Can someone explain why, if I calculate manually the KS test statistic, the result is different from when I use `scipy.stats.kstest`?

```
>>> sample = np.array([1000,2000,2500,3000,5000])
>>> ecdf = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
>>> cdf = stats.weibull_min(0.3, 100, 4000).cdf(sample)
>>> abs(ecdf - cdf).max()
0.3454961536273503

>>> stats.kstest(rvs=sample, cdf=stats.weibull_min(0.3, 100, 4000).cdf)
KstestResult(statistic=0.4722995454382698, pvalue=0.1534647709785294)
```

Comment: One way to investigate this is to plot the Weibull cdf as a smooth line and the empirical cdf with stair steps and see what is the greatest difference. Maybe to make it easier to think about, try a Gaussian cdf with mean 0 and variance 1, then try different mean and variance, then try Weibull. The point is just to start with something very simple and add complexity by steps.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I realized the mistake I made, so I will answer my onwn question. The KS-Statistic can't be calculated as `abs(ecdf - cdf).max()`, bacause of the right-continuity / left-discontinuity of the ECDF. The correct approach is:

```
>>> sample = np.array([1000, 2000, 2500, 3000, 5000])
>>> ecdf = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
>>> cdf = stats.weibull_min(0.3, 100, 4000).cdf(sample)
>>> max([(ecdf[1:] - cdf).max(), (cdf - ecdf[:-1]).max()])
0.4722995454382698
```